# How to send email with Node.js from a cloud server without external smtp server?

Tags: node.js, email, gmail, sendmail, nodemailer

I am trying to send email to my Gmail address from a Linux cloud server (Digital Ocean, Linode, Vultr) using [Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) that provides [Sendmail Transport](https://nodemailer.com/transports/sendmail/) so that I don't have to use an external SMTP server. I am testing their [basic example](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/blob/master/examples/sendmail.js):

```
async function main() {
    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({sendmail: true})

    let message = {
        from: ...,
        to: ...,
        subject: 'Nodemailer is unicode friendly ✔',
        text: 'Hello to myself!'
    }

    let info = await transporter.sendMail(message)
    console.log('Message sent successfully as %s', info.messageId)
}

main().catch(err => {
    console.error(err.message)
    process.exit(1)
})
```

The script ends with a success message, however, the email never arrives, not even to my spam folder.

Is there any way to diagnose it and find out what is wrong or maybe use another Node.js mailing package?

Comment: Seems this transport just run `sendmail` program. So if you have access to linux terminal you can run command like `mailq`.

Comment: @YaroslavGaponov Tried `mailq` and it is giving `Mail queue is empty`